# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout.addLayoutComponent(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-absolutelayout

Al modificar mi layout de programa desde el apartado gráfico en netbeans, al querer ejecutar la pestaña, carga de clientes me sale este error. Esa pestaña debe acceder a una base de datos y enviarle datos, pero los errores que me salen son de layout. Antes de hacer estas modificaciones en el apartado grafico no ocurrian. No se como solucionar estos problemas.

```
    package Ventanas;

import DBConeccion.CrudSql;


public class CargarCliente extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

   
    public CargarCliente() {
        initComponents();
    }

    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtCargaNombre = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtCargaApellido = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtCargaDNI = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtCargaContacto = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txtInfoAdicional = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setClosable(true);
        setIconifiable(true);
        setMaximizable(true);
        setResizable(true);
        setTitle("Cargar Cliente");

        jLabel1.setText("Nombre");

        jLabel2.setText("Apellido");

        txtCargaNombre.setBorder(null);

        txtCargaApellido.setBorder(null);
        txtCargaApellido.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtCargaApellidoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        txtCargaDNI.setBorder(null);
        txtCargaDNI.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtCargaDNIActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setText("DNI");

        jLabel4.setText("Contacto");

        txtCargaContacto.setBorder(null);
        txtCargaContacto.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtCargaContactoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        txtInfoAdicional.setColumns(20);
        txtInfoAdicional.setRows(5);
        txtInfoAdicional.setText("\n");
        txtInfoAdicional.setBorder(null);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txtInfoAdicional);

        jLabel6.setText("Informacion adicional");

        jButton1.setText("Guardar Cliente");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(53, 53, 53)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(txtCargaNombre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(txtCargaApellido, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(txtCargaDNI, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(txtCargaContacto, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addContainerGap(51, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(txtCargaNombre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(txtCargaApellido, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtCargaDNI, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(txtCargaContacto, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(69, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void txtCargaApellidoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    
    }                                                

    private void txtCargaDNIActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
     
    }                                           

   CrudSql objetoCrud= new CrudSql();
    
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // Peticion SQL de "Guardado de cliente"  ---------------------------------------------------------
    objetoCrud.insertar(txtCargaNombre.getText(), txtCargaApellido.getText(), txtCargaDNI.getText(), txtCargaContacto.getText(), txtInfoAdicional.getText());
    
       
    /**     Hacer que boton 'Guardar Cliente' cierre la pestaña cargar cliente  */
        InterfazInicial verventana = new InterfazInicial();
        verventana.setVisible(true);
        verventana.show();   
    }                                        

    private void txtCargaContactoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        
    }                                                
    

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtCargaApellido;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtCargaContacto;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtCargaDNI;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtCargaNombre;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea txtInfoAdicional;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

El error es:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
> at org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout.addLayoutComponent(Unknown Source)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1152)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.addImpl(JLayeredPane.java:233)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JDesktopPane.addImpl(JDesktopPane.java:484)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:436)
> at Ventanas.InterfazInicial.AgregarClienteActionPerformed(InterfazInicial.java:154)
> at Ventanas.InterfazInicial$3.actionPerformed(InterfazInicial.java:140)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:369)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1012)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1056)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6614)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6379)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2769)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)

Comment: te recomiendo primero reportarlo al equipo de netbeans mediante https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/new?assignees=&labels=kind%3Abug%2Cneeds%3Atriage&template=netbeans_bug_report.yml

Comment: lo siguiente que puedes intentar es usando matisse cambiarle el layout desde el nivel de frame a alguno otro y ver si desaparece el error

Comment: voy a intentar las dos cosas! muchísimas gracias por responder

Answer (score 0):

El problema se soluciono toqueteando todos los layouts y cambiándole las dependencias visuales, aparentemente hice magia porque todavía no lo entiendo, muchísimas gracias por responder.